# MS ACCESS Combining to result sets

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT c.siteno, a.sitename, a.location, Count(a.status) AS ChargeablePermit

FROM (PermitStatus AS a LEFT JOIN states AS b ON a.status = b.statusheading) 
LEFT JOIN    Sitedetails AS c ON a.zone = c.compexzone
WHERE b.statusheading like "Chargeable"  and a.loaded_date between 
(select monthstart  from ChargeDate) and (select Monthend from ChargeDate)
GROUP BY a.sitename, c.siteno, a.location;
```

This query returns me the count of chargeable permits by site
Mar14

#### Siteno (1) Sitename (site1) Location (location1) Chargeablepermit (30)

these calculations are based on the period determined by the two sub selects (i.e. for  the month of March 14)
i was wondering if i could change the date range covered by the subselects (i.e.to April 14) and  do math on (subtract one count from the other) the counts of chargeable permits from the two different result sets  and have that result displayed on the on one table

for instance if April 14 was

April

#### Siteno (1) Sitename (Site1) Location (Location1)     ChargeablePermit (40)  Difference (10)

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way it seems you are proposing, you would simply double-up your SQL within a UNION query to return the data sets for the 2 periods, and then perform an aggregate on the results:

```
SELECT SUM(CP) FROM (
  SELECT (ChargeablePermit * -1) AS CP FROM ... WHERE dates = Date1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ChargeablePermit AS CP FROM ... WHERE dates = Date2
)
```

Depending on how many records you're dealing with, a UNION like this could be quite slow however. So the other approach would be to turn your SQL into an Append query which inserts the output into a temp table. You would run the query for each period, before running a 2nd query to aggregate the results from the temp table.

Also you should consider using joins to filter your results rather than subqueries.

Comment: i am using ms access before attemptiing to union all i tried to just  sum the count of CP bhut i am getting an error that staes syntax error in from cluase                                                  i tried SELECT c.siteno, a.sitename, a.location, Count(a.status) AS CP

FROM (PermitStatus AS a LEFT JOIN states AS b ON a.status = b.statusheading) 
LEFT JOIN    Sitedetails AS c ON a.zone = c.compexzone
WHERE b.statusheading like "Chargeable"  and a.loaded_date between 
(select monthstart  from ChargeDate) and (select Monthend from ChargeDate)
GROUP BY a.sitename, c.siteno, a.location;

Comment: My SQL example was just to illustrate how your 2 queries could be aggregated using UNION. Your 2 subqueries must be fully functioning & independent queries with their own standard SELECT clauses. Once they are separately returning the data you expect, you can stack them with a UNION in between per my illustration. Once you are getting all the rows you expect from the combined output, then you can wrap them inside an aggregate statement to get your totals.